# Ruby on Rails - multiple database connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing an application where it lets users to establish many number of database connections with a has-many relationship between user and connections. The connections are passive until the user manually connects each. The motive is to perform queries on them, parallely.

I don't find good tutorials related to this, can you help me with some tips on how to accomplish this ?

Comment: You want users to be able to dictate how many connections they make to one or more databases?  Also, when you say parallelism do you mean concurrency?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I sure hope you put in limits otherwise a malicious, or ignorant, user could take you down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching for a bit, turns out there's a much simpler approach using ActiveRecord Connection pool.

1. Setup a relationship between users and the database connections, in this case user 1 .. n connections.
2. Make sure the model record can individually connect using

   ```
   obj = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...spec...) 

   obj.connection.exec_query("Select * from users") 
   # the response is in the form of ActiveResult, which allows flexible operations around the result.
   ```
3. Close the connection once done with the database.

References:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionHandler.html

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html

Answer (score 1):

For my application I use this gem

https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus

have good documentation and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use activerecord you can go two ways:

- dynamic class creation: see [Dynamically create a class inherited from ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319138/dynamically-create-a-class-inherited-from-activerecord)
- define multiple classes and use the one needed, if they are in different schemes you need to specify the connection into the model itself, only feasable if the number of tables/models is not too high
  see my answer at [Connecting to two different database in ruby at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862704/connecting-to-two-different-database-in-ruby-at-runtime/39863010#39863010)

Here an example how to use such a model, the class_name parameter is the name of the model to be used. It's from a Sinatra app but I'm sure you'll be able to adapt it for Rails. It's a backend for a ExtJs javascript app using multiple models expecting JSON as result.

```
 # controller

%w(create read update destroy).each do |action|
  [:get, :post].each do |method|
      send(method, "/path/#{action}") do
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        content_type :json
        if params[:store]
          store = Object.const_get(params[:store]) 
        else
          store = Signal
        end
        resp = send(action, store, params)
        jsonp(resp)
      end
  end
end

# in helper.rb

def read (class_name, params)
  params = params.symbolize_keys
  default = {store: 'Signaal', limit: 10, sort: 'id', order: 'ASC', start: 0, user: '0'}
  params = default.merge params
  generic_data_getter(class_name, params, params[:start], params[:limit], params[:sort], params[:dir])
end

def generic_data_getter (class_name, params, start=0, limit=10, sort='id', dir='ASC')
  selection = build_selection(class_name, params)
  data = class_name.where(selection).offset(start).limit(limit).order("#{sort} #{dir}")
  {:success => true, :totalCount => data.except(:offset, :limit, :order).count, :result => data.as_json}
end
```

If not or for simple predefined searches or speed you can connect and disconnect as a connection is needed. Here an example for Oracle.

```
require 'oci8'
CONN = OCI8.new('scheme','password','dbserver')
sql = '....'
CONN.exec(sql) {|record|puts record.join(',')}
CONN.logoff
```

Be aware of malicius use like code injection.